Is the Jónsson-Tarski topos local?
The category of Jónsson-Tarski algebras is a topos. It is presented as such in Example A2.1.11(i) in Johnstone's Sketches of an elephant.
A geometric morphism is local if its direct image functor has a fully faithful right adjoint.
Is the canonical geometric morphism from the JT-topos to the topos of sets local?
(My guess is not because I cannot imagine a site for it that would make it local. What would be an actual proof?)
(One possibility would be to show that the points functor does not preserve colimits; but this seems to require some knowledge of the JT-algebras to pick the simplest colimit that fails to be preserved.)

As it turns out, the topos of Jónsson-Tarski algebras is not local. This is because it is possible for a nonempty Jónsson-Tarski algebra to contain no idempotents, so the terminal Jónsson-Tarski algebra is not projective.
For the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ (not including $0$), one could consider the bijection $f:\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}$ given by going down the antidiagonals of an infinite square grid. The "squares" $f(n, n)$ are then the centered square numbers (OEIS sequence A001844), as one could easily verify. This Jónsson-Tarski algebra, however, contains the idempotent $1$. This could be fixed by interchanging the values of $f(1, 1)$ and $f(1, 2)$.
So, define a new bijection $g:\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}$ with $g(1, 1)=2$ and $g(1, 2)=1$ and $g(m, n)=f(m, n)$ otherwise. Then, for $n>1$, $g(n, n)$ is the $n$th centered square number, which is never equal to $n$. Also, $g(1, 1)=2$. This Jónsson-Tarski algebra therefore does not contain any idempotents. So, for this Jónsson-Tarski algebra $(\mathbb{N}, g)$, there are no Jónsson-Tarski algebra homomorphisms $1 \to (\mathbb{N}, g)$. This shows that the terminal Jónsson-Tarski algebra is not projective.
But the terminal object of any local topos is projective. So, the topos of Jónsson-Tarski algebras is not local.
